# IPV6 url to load tomcat in browser

Tags: tomcat, browser, ipv6, ipv4

I have started tomcat on port 8086 linux box which is IPV6 and IPV4 enbaled.
Now, I am trying to load it in firefox/chrome browser using following url
:

http://[1001:efac::100]:8086

It fails to load with IPV6 url but with IPV4 url http://10.99.112.76:8086 it loads successfully.

Could you please help in what configurations I will need to do to work IPV6 url in browser.

**EDIT:**

```
    <Connector port="8082" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
    connectionTimeout="20000"
    redirectPort="8443" />

    <Connector address="0.0.0.0" port="8083" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
    connectionTimeout="20000"
    redirectPort="8443" />
```

Comment: Can you please show your configuration?

Comment: Hi @SanderSteffann  which configuration I can share with you?

Comment: Well, considering that you ask a question about Tomcat... Your Tomcat configuration would be a good starting point :)

Comment: Adding my connector details in question above